# Why my LazyVerticalGrid in android compose is laggy

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

**The Problem:**
my list very laggy and this happen not just in emulator, what am i doing wrong?

**What i tried:**
i checked what making this problem and found that when i remove the onEvent line in LazyGridScope the list smoother.

```
@Composable
fun LevelsScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    levelsViewModel: LevelsViewModel = hiltViewModel()
){

    val gameInfo by levelsViewModel.getGameInfo.observeAsState()

    val uiState = levelsViewModel.uiState
    val listScrollState = rememberLazyGridState()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val levelsList = getLevelsList()

    LazyVerticalGrid(
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(
            start = 12.dp,
            top = 16.dp,
            end = 12.dp,
            bottom = 16.dp
        ),
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        state = listScrollState

    ){
        items(levelsList.size) {item ->
            CustomListItem(
                levelsListIndex = levelsList[item],
                onCardClick = {
                    levelsViewModel.updateCurrentLevel(item+1)
                    navController.navigate("question")
                },
                lastLevel = gameInfo?.lastLevel ?: 0
            )
        }

        levelsViewModel.onEvent(LevelsEvents.OnScrollStateChange(listScrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex))

        coroutineScope.launch {
            listScrollState.scrollToItem(uiState.value.scrollState)
        }
    }
}
```

my viewmodel code:

```
private val _uiState = mutableStateOf(LevelsState())
val uiState: State<LevelsState> get() = _uiState

fun onEvent(event: LevelsEvents){
    when (event){
        is LevelsEvents.OnScrollStateChange -> {
            _uiState.value = _uiState.value.copy(scrollState = event.scrollPosition)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested in the release build?

Comment: wrap `getLevelList()` inside `remember { getLevelList(levelsList, key = { level -> level.id }) }`.
you can also pass a key in `items()

Comment: thise did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `onEvent` inside `LaunchedEffect` but outside of `LazyVerticalGrid`:

```
.................
val listScrollState = rememberLazyGridState()
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

LaunchedEffect(listScrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex) {
  levelsViewModel.onEvent(LevelsEvents.OnScrollStateChange(listScrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex))
}
.................
```

Comment: when I use this there is a warning "Frequently changing state should not be directly read in composable function" and the list is still laggy. when I use onEvent in the coroutineScope everything works fine but is it a good thing to do?

Comment: Not sure. But you can try. I have another idea if that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try snapshotFlow, with distinctUntilChanged.

```
LaunchedEffect(listState) {
    snapshotFlow { listState.firstVisibleItemIndex }
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .collect {
            // event
        }
}
```